# useState acting strange

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm using this code to get a random number in the range of min-max. for some reason, I get numbers that are bigger than max.
(the console.log shows that the min and max are set correctly.)
(I'm showing here the relevant code. this is not the whole file.)

```
const RandomNumber = () => {
    const [min, setMin] = useState(0)
    const [max, setMax] = useState(0)
    const [rand, setRand] = useState(0)
    const classes = useStyles();
  
    const setRandom = () => {
        console.log(min);
        console.log(max);
        let random = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min)
        console.log(random);
        setRand(random)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Stack direction="row" spacing={2} className={classes.root}>
                <TextField
                    id="filled-number"
                    label="Min-Number"
                    type="number"
                    InputLabelProps={{
                        shrink: true,
                    }}
                    variant="filled"
                    onChange={(e) => setMin(e.target.value)}
                />
                <TextField
                    id="filled-number"
                    label="Max-Number"
                    type="number"
                    InputLabelProps={{
                        shrink: true,
                    }}
                    variant="filled"
                    onChange={(e) => setMax(e.target.value)}
                />
                <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
                    <Button variant="outlined" className={classes.button} onClick={setRandom}>Get Random!</Button>
                </Stack>

            </Stack>
            <h1>rand is: {rand}</h1>
        </>
    );
}

export default RandomNumber;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to convert your `e.target.value` in `setMax` and `setMin` to number

```
e.target.value && !isNaN(e.target.value) && setMax(Number(e.target.value))
```

Similar for `setMin`

```
e.target.value && !isNaN(e.target.value) && setMin(Number(e.target.value))
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because `e.target.value` is a `string` type, so the problem is on this line of code.

> `let random = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min)`

Say for example `max = "25"` and `min="9"` (this is string because you set from `e.target.value` without casting it to `int`,

`"25" - "9" = 14` works fine, but

> `Math.floor(....) + min`

`int + string = string`

So say for example `Math.floor` result is 12,

`12 + "9" = "129"`